# Cookies rejected by chrome

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I want to implement jwts stored in httpOnly cookeis into my applicaition but the cookies are being rejected by chrome and an empty cookie object is being recieved at the backend.

This is how the cookie is being set in the auth controller triggered by the /login api end point where the refresh token is created and stored in a cookie

```
res.cookie("jwt",refreshToken,{httpOnly: true, sameSite: "lax", maxAge: 24*60*60*1000});
```

Refresh controller

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../model/User');

const handleRefresh = async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    if(!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401);

    const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;
    const foundUser = await User.findOne({refreshToken: refreshToken}).exec();

    jwt.verify(
        refreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
        (err,decoded) => {
            const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles);
            if(err || decoded.username !== foundUser.username) return res.sendStatus(403);
            
            const accessToken = jwt.sign({
                "userInfo":{
                    "username": decoded.username,
                    "roles": roles
                }
            },
            process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
            {expiresIn: "300s"});

            return res.json({"accessToken":accessToken});
        }
    );
}


module.exports = {handleRefresh};
```

Refresh function in react making a call to the refresh endpoint

```
    const useRefreshToken = () => {
    const {setUser} = useAuth();

    const refresh = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('/refresh',{
            withCredentials: true
        });
        console.log(response);
        setUser(prevState => {
            console.log(prevState);
            console.log(response.data.accessToken);
            return {...prevState, accessToken: response.data.accessToken}
        })}

        return refresh;
    }
```

axios instance

```
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:4500";


export default axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
});
```

Whenever I call the useRefeshToken func and make the request through my react application I get an error which is as a result of the `if(!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401);` in my refresh controller, meaning the cookie object is empty. But when I use Thunder Client to make requests to the same refresh endpoint the cookie is sent and I get back my jwt object.

PS - I have already handled the CORS so this isn't a cors error.

Comment: " I get an error and the cookie object comes back empty" - What error do you get?

Comment: if(!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401);   This is how I handled the case of no cookie being present in the refresh controller so I get a 401

Comment: Code looks good, I'd recommend search for `expressjs` related cookie question to narrow it down.

Comment: Haven't found anything helpful sadly